# Azure Stream Analytics Job degrading while pushing data to cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I Have data getting pushed from Azure IoT Hub -> Stream Analytics -> CosmosDB

I had 1 simulated device and my cosmos DB collection was of 1000 RU/s working fine .
now i have made it 10 simulated devices and my Cosmos DB collection scaled to 15000 RU/s still my stream analytics getting degraded .

Is there i need to increase number of parallel connections to collection ?

can we make it more optimal As Azure pricing of Cosmos DB , Depend on throughput and RU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we make it more optimal as Azure pricing of Cosmos DB, depend on
>   throughput and RUs?

I just want to share some thoughts with you about improving write performance of Cosmos db here.

***1.Consistency Level***

Based on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-documentdb-output#tune-consistency-availability-and-latency):

> Depending on what levels of read consistency your scenario needs
>   against read and write latency, you can choose a consistency level on
>   your database account.

You could try to set Consistency Level as `Eventually`. Details please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels#consistency-levels).

***2.Indexing:***

Based on the document:

> by default, Azure Cosmos DB enables synchronous indexing on each CRUD
>   operation to your collection. This is another useful option to control
>   the write/read performance in Azure Cosmos DB.

Please try to set index lazy. Also, remove useless index.

***3.Partition:***

Based on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-documentdb-output#data-partitioning-in-cosmos-db):

> Azure Cosmos DB unlimited are the recommended approach for
>   partitioning your data, as Azure Cosmos DB automatically scales
>   partitions based on your workload. When writing to unlimited
>   containers, Stream Analytics uses as many parallel writers as previous
>   query step or input partitioning scheme.

Please partition your collection and pass the partition key in output to improve write performance.

Comment: right now when i created COSMOS DB collection i have partitioned it by using deviceId , and for cosmos DB right now i am using default indexing .  And each record contains 130 feilds . And All my queries will be depending on deviceId and time ( last hour and last day ) when i want to read the data . so partition should be by deviceId and timestamp ( converted to Day ) ? And when you that partition while writing means in sql query in stream analytics ?

Comment: @AmjathKhan The default index mode should be none and the consistency level default should be session.You could adjust it to see if any progress.

Comment: @AmjathKhan I think partitioned by deviceId is fine.You could adjust other 2 factors,maybe it it optimize for performance.I just share official suggestions in the document here.

Comment: I have removed all indexes i am using 3 Streaming job units and 5000 RU/s cosmos DB collection .  Data i am sending per second is of size 38 KB/ sec ( 20 messages together size) And it has 185 fields in each message . It is Eventual consistency still it shows increase throghput for cosmos DB